# Cannot resolve RecyclerView and CardView Gradle dependencies

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to add these two lines to dependencies in build.gardle:

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerView-v7:23.1.1'

compile 'com.android.support:cardView-v7:23.1.1'
```

But, I got these errors:

> Error:(25,13) Failed to resolve:
> com.android.support:recyclerView-v7:23.1.1
>
> Error:(26,13) Failed to resolve:
> com.android.support:cardView-v7:23.1.1

Answer (score 1):

Have you downloaded the latest librarys in the sdk?

Try:

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.2.1'
```

If it does not work check the sdk and update the support library if necessary!

Comment: 23.2.1 is also available

Comment: oh I didnt check since a while. I'll edit my post! :D

Answer (score 1):

Not sure where you copied those lines from, but you have a typo. The `v` is lowercase in "view"

```
compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1"
compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1"
```

Answer (score 0):

compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:+'

compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'

Use this instead of defining "v7:23.1.1"

Comment: This is very brittle. Never use just `+` in a production environment. `23.+` would be better

Answer (score 0):

Version 24 is available now so you can use

```
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.1'
```